# display data after executed through form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX, this is my first project. First, the user input a sentence in `index.php` through a form and pass data to the `executed.php` to return a formatted sentence. I have done all the logical work here but I can't get the data display in the original page (`index.php`). I used ajax to do this task but failed.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(event) { 

            var postForm = { //Fetch form data
                'name'  : $('input[name=name]').val() 
            };

            $.ajax({ //Process the form using $.ajax()
                type        : 'POST',
                url         : 'executed.php',  
                data        : 'postForm',
                dataType    : 'json',
                success     : function(data) {

                    $('#success').html(data); 
                    }
                });
                event.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default submit
            });
        });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="postForm" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><textarea rows="4" name="name" id="name" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your sentence here..."></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="s1" value="Check"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><span class="throw_error"></span></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="success"></div>
```

and in the executed.php, after all the logical work, i want to display $a and $b on the `index.php`so I store it in the `$form_data` and use `echo json_encode($form_data)` to make it appear in the `index.php` but it is not working

Comment: no idea why you tagged as php if you're not going to show relevant code. How do we know `executed.php` isn't failing here. Edit: I removed the php tag; you can add it in once you've shown relevance.

Comment: it will not working itself you should use   success: function(data){alert(data);} in ajax code  and event.preventDefault();  outside ajax not inside

Comment: @Fred-ii- i tested the executed the original way (pass data and display directly on it) and it worked fine. Now i just want to apply AJAX to display data in one page

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef i updated the code. but still not working

Comment: check executed.php path .. up to your files structure .. may be you need to use url : "../executed.php"  or url : "folder/executed.php";

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the data from the ajax call and then do something with it.

```
$.ajax({ //Process the form using $.ajax()
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'gramcheck.php',  
    data        : postForm,
    dataType    : 'json',
    success     : function(data){
         // AJAX has succeeded, and returned output to 'data' var
         $('#target_location').html(data);  // Put the code into some target

         // -OR- //

         // Further JS processing with data var
    }
});
```